# Angular get value from dynamically generated mat select

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Angular material to make a reactive form that look like this:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILMZH.png)

With this code I make a dynamically generated mat select and an input, but I don't know how to get the value from all of these.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let number of [].constructor(cantConsumibles)">
    <mat-select placeholder="Selecciona un consumible" class="form-control" 
                formControlName="consumibles">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let consumible of consumibles" [value]="consumible">
            {{consumible.CodConsumible}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="consumibles" placeholder="Cantidad">
</div>

<div align="end">
    <button mat-button (click)="agregarConsumible(true)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
    <button mat-button (click)="agregarConsumible(false)"><mat-icon>remove</mat-icon></button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
cantConsumibles: number = 0;

   agregarConsumible(flag: boolean): void {
   (flag) ? this.cantConsumibles++ : this.cantConsumibles--;
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select API documents say that we could register a change with `@Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter<C>` https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

So let's add that method on our select to know, what was selected.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" (selectionChange)="onFoodSelection($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
       {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

We then console.log the event value but also save the event value to a variable for later use.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  output: any;

  foods = [
    {value: 'product10', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'product20', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'product30', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
    {value: 'product40', viewValue: 'Lasagne'},
  ];


  onFoodSelection(event:any) {
    this.output = event.value;
    console.log(event.value)
  }
}
```

Follow same principal on other elemens (select, input, checkbox etc.) getting the event on change in template and doing something with in in typescript code part.

Here is a small example for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-select-change-event-binding-tta13p?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts